# Navigation drawer opens blank activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I am developing an application where i use navigation drawer. I am calling navigation drawer by clicking on button. but problem is that i get blank page when i press button, my first item is not chosen as main, even i indicated it as main.

here is my code, this is my mainActivity:

```
    package sightsOfAlmaty;

import sightsOfAlmaty.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import sightsOfAlmaty.NavDrawerItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.new1.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class sightsOfAlmaty extends ActionBarActivity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
protected ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private static boolean isLaunch = true;

// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
protected CharSequence mTitle;

// slide menu items
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;
protected FrameLayout frameLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sights);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
    frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame_container);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items to array
    // Home
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    // Find People
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    // Photos
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    // Communities, Will add a counter here
    //navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
    // Pages
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
    // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
//  navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));


    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();
    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
            adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                    navDrawerItems);

            mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
            mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

            // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            //R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);

        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
            super.onDrawerStateChanged(newState);
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    /**
     * As we are calling BaseActivity from manifest file and this base activity is intended just to add navigation drawer in our app.
     * We have to open some activity with layout on launch. So we are checking if this BaseActivity is called first time then we are opening our first activity.
     * */
    if(isLaunch){
         /**
          *Setting this flag false so that next time it will not open our first activity.
          *We have to use this flag because we are using this BaseActivity as parent activity to our other activity. 
          *In this case this base activity will always be call when any child activity will launch.
          */
        isLaunch = false;
        displayView(0);
    }
   }

   /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
    * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    }

   /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
    */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;

    Intent intent;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        /*intent = new Intent(this, HomeFragment.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        this.startActivity(intent);*/
        startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeFragment.class));
        return;
    case 1:
        //fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
        break;
    /*case 2:
        fragment = new PhotosFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new CommunityFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new PagesFragment();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
        break;
    */
    default:
        break;
    }

    /*if (fragment != null) {
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();*/

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    //} else {
        // error in creating fragment
    //  Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    //}
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

   /**
    * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
    * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
    */

   @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

   @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    }
```

and this is one of the items in navigation drawer (first item, that had to be opened by default):

```
package sightsOfAlmaty;

import java.util.Hashtable;


import com.example.new1.GPSTracker;

import com.example.new1.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
public class HomeFragment extends sightsOfAlmaty {

public HomeFragment(){}

private GoogleMap map;
GPSTracker gps;

Marker marker;
private Hashtable<String, String> markers;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private DisplayImageOptions options;
protected static int position;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mTitle);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, frameLayout);
    /**
     * Setting title and itemChecked  

    */

    gps = new GPSTracker(this);

    LatLng myloc = new LatLng(gps.getLatitude(), gps.longitude);

    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map2)).getMap();
    map.getUiSettings(  ).setZoomControlsEnabled(true); // true to enable
     map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myloc, 15));
     map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(13), 2000, null);



}
 }
```

here are screenshots:http://savepic.net/6400885.htm , http://savepic.net/6399861.htm (in case you did not understand what exactly i mean)

i got it after changing fragments to activities, so please help me how to solve my problem. Any suggestions, answers, comments are  appreciated!

Comment: Many says it's best to use fragments instead of activities, but I'm in the same boat as you. Hope someone shows how to make it inside activity!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late, but here we go. This is what you are using to "navigate" when you launch MainActivity.

```
    if(isLaunch){
     /**
      *Setting this flag false so that next time it will not open our first activity.
      *We have to use this flag because we are using this BaseActivity as parent activity to our other activity. 
      *In this case this base activity will always be call when any child activity will launch.
      */
    isLaunch = false;
    displayView(0);
}
```

In my applications, I use this piece of code. When you had never ran your app, it doesn't have a saved instance, so you can navigate to wherever index you want in your navdrawer when savedInstanceState is null (since your app is not running in background or is standby). The method onCreate, inside MainActivity gives you "savedInstanceState" value :)

Well, here is the code:

```
    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
         displayView(0);
    }
```

Use it inside onCreate.

Does this works for you?